# return java NullPointerException parsing edittext to int

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to enter a number in an EditText and parse it to an Integer but the I have the error in the title.

Here is my code :

```
final Context contextmatrice = this;
    public static int n=0;
    public EditText editsize;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_matrice);
    }

    public void ToAddMat (View ViewToAddMat) {


        final Dialog matricesize = new Dialog(contextmatrice);
        matricesize.setContentView(R.layout.dialogmatricesize);

        editsize = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editsize);


        Button dialogbutton = (Button) matricesize.findViewById(R.id.closedialog);
        dialogbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                n = Integer.parseInt(editsize.getText().toString());
                matricesize.dismiss();
                Intent IntentToAddMat = new Intent(MatriceActivity.this, AddMatriceActivity.class);
                startActivity(IntentToAddMat);

            }

        });
```

Here is my dialog.xml :

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Entrez la taille de\n vos matrices carrées"
    android:id="@+id/editsize"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:background="#ffffff"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK"
    android:onClick="closedialog"
    android:id="@+id/closedialog"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

On button click a Dialog is launched, the user can enter a value and on another button click to close the dialog and launch another activity, the value is given to the variable **n**.

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
editsize = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editsize);
```

This code is getting view from activity layout, not dialog. Change to this:

```
editsize = (EditText) matricesize.findViewById(R.id.editsize);
```

Like, when you are getting view for button.

Answer (score 2):

the EditText belongs to the dialog's layout. As you did for the button, you should use `matricesize` to retrieve it. E.g.

```
editsize = (EditText) matricesize.findViewById(R.id.editsize);
```

Comment: just couple of seconds :)

Answer (score 1):

if the `EditText` has no content , `getText()` return null.

Comment: it does not. It returns an empty string

Comment: if this answer is right then user will get `NumberFormatException` instead of `NPE`

Comment: No . null.toString() throw NPE.And editsize = (EditText) matricesize.findViewById(R.id.editsize) seems to be right.